# How to prevent Chrome and other browsers to convert email address like text into mailto links?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, mailto

I was putting a text like this. address&login=personal_id@domain.com, on our web site just as plain text. But the browser displays it as it is inside a link anchor.

How does one stop the browser from creating links automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Set span tags around `@` like `<span>@</span>`.

Example:

```
name<span>@</span>domain.com
```